# Java execution time affected by string formatting?

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I was doing some performance test (sum up around a million integers) with the following simple code:

```
final int[] array = new int[1024 * 1024];

// populate values
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = i % 100;
}

long start, end, sum = 0;

start = System.nanoTime();

// calculate sum
for (int i : array) {
    sum += i;
}

end = System.nanoTime() - start;

System.out.println(end);
```

Average execution time was around **1.8ms**.

Then I decided to change test results presentation. I replaced `System.out.println(end)` with the following statement (formatted string) :

```
System.out.printf("Time in %dns, sum: %d\n", end, sum);
```

And it was very surprising when I noticed that my average execution time was around **2.8ms**. It is only a millisecond more (not a big deal) but on the other hand it is about **50%** slower. More to that, test results presentation (and formatting) is located after end time measure is taken, so theoretically it **should not** affect average execution time.

Do you know why average execution time takes more time after adding `System.out.printf` statement? Is it caused by reordering (formatting executed before assigning value to the `end` variable)?

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce these measurements? A millisecond difference is in the range of random noise, no matter how large a *relative* difference it is.

Comment: You're not executing enough tests. Do it 100.000 times and see how both approaches measure up. A quick few tests on my machine shows they are all in the same range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you cannot draw any conclusions from this.  Basically, your benchmark is flawed:

1. It does not take the necessary steps to *warm up* the JVM before it captures the measurement.
2. The loop that does the "work" that you are measuring can be optimized away.  The compiler (`javac` or the JIT compiler) can deduce that the `sum` is never used, and therefore not calculate it.

Either of these flaws could distort the results you are seeing.

---

For what it is worth, if the benchmark was properly written, then the fancy formatting should not contribute to the measured time at all.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Stephane. It looks like the issue was related to point #2. When I added additional print statement with `sum` (`System.out.println(sum)`) then both results came to the same level of 2.8ms. Good catch.

Comment: Yes, Dead Code Elimination is at work here. Definitely not by `javac`, but by JIT compiler. If you benchmarked properly, the difference with and without using `sum` would have been much larger. Lesson: measure with utmost care and use a proper measurement harness such as `jmh`.